# Aliasing in C++

Tags: c++

In C++, I've always known the intialization of `Foo& f = _f;` to create an alias to the member `_f`.  So, from that point on I can call `f` and it's just like I was calling `_f`.

I have tried doing this where I am setting an alias to the return of a getter function, and it doesn't seem to be working.  How come?  This is what I'm trying..

```
Foo &f = c->getFoo(); //where I have a pointer c that points to an object of type Foo.
```

Comment: what does `getFoo` return? for this to work, `getFoo` needs to return an lvalue reference to non-const.

Comment: You cannot make a reference for a temporary variable.

Comment: Can you post how getFoo() is implemented?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the declaration, I assume that the problem you have is that you can't get a non const reference for a temporary.  So

```
Foo const&f = c->getFoo();
```

but

```
Foo f(c->getFoo());
```

would probably work as well.

Comment: So the returned result from getFoo() has to be constant for the alias to work?

Comment: If you return a reference, you have to bind it to a reference with the same CV qualification.  If you return a value, you can only bind it to a const reference (the fact that the value is const or not doesn't matter) but in that case assigning it will probably work as well.

Answer (score 0):

doing Foo &f = c->getFoo() is *not* an alias. It actually stores the returning address of getFoo() in a reference (Gives you the same object as getFoo() is returning).

It depends on the return type of getFoo(). For example, if your getFoo() returns a Foo& it would work. If your getFoo() returns a const Foo&, then you'll have to do Foo const &f = getFoo().

However, in both cases, you have to make sure that the object returned by getFoo is available in the class c scope, not only in the getFoo() scope (Check that it's not a temporary).